# How to address MongoDB database with hyphen in name in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I need to remove any element from a Mongo database when I have two databases:

1. mydatabase
2. data-test-second

With the first database this isn't a problem, I use MongoClient:

```
self.db = self.client.mydatabase
result = self.db.test.delete_one({"name": 'testelement'})
```

bBt when I use this for a second database I have a problem with:

```
self.db = self.client.data-test-second
```

underlining the database name, how I can write this? Or I can't use this solution for the second name?

Comment: its hard to follow your code. Can you explain it a bit more please? I think your issue is that you overwrite the first db instance with your second assignment.

Comment: `self.db = self.client.data - test - second` is a bad example. Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, you need to descibe what problem you have, i.e. what you observed when running the example code. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case that your database name is not valid as an object name in Python, you need to address the database differently:

```
self.db = self.client["data-test-second"]
```

In general, it is probably advisable to always use this pattern.

For more information, you can refer to the [documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#getting-a-database).

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how I can create a database from code ? example new database name: "testing123" how write this ?

Comment: Please note that the comments are not for asking new questions. Please refer to the documentation or search StackOverflow for the answer to your new question.